# MS SQL 2019 Always on AG - Readable to secondary

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019, high-availability

I have a 2-node cluster that uses Always on AG, with multiple AGs and databases. All the AGs have the same properties:

- *Connections in primary role*: **Allow all connections**
- *Readable secondary*: **no**

I wonder why the readable secondary is set to *no*? I know this is the default setting, but is there a best practice around this? Is it better to have it on **read**?

We had some issues with the logins and jobs, with connection failures, when the node failed over to secondary, and I wonder if this has anything to do with it. Everything works fine when it is on the primary node.

I took over this position without any information about the set up, and I'm new to the DBA role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder why the readable secondary is set to no?

That's the default option. You can change it based on your needs and available licensing.

> i know this is deafult setting, but is it a best practis around this?

Set it for what you need. If you need secondaries to be readable and have the licensing for it, then do it. If you don't, then don't. Shouldn't controversial.

> is it better to have it on "read"?

It is if you need to read from secondary replicas.

> We had some issues with the logins and jobs, with connection fail, when the node failover to secondary and i wonder if this has anything to do with it.

It does not. Generally this means the AG wasn't properly configured with logins and jobs for the other replicas.